# Why is it "Ça fait plus de" and not "Ça fait plus que"?

Tags: grammaire

In a film I was watching, a character said "Ça fait plus **d'un** an depuis je suis allé." But I don't understand why it's not "Ça fait plus **qu'un** an depuis je suis allé."

After all, the first transliteration is "It's been **more** of a year since I went." whereas the second would mean "It's been more **than** a year since I went." and the second is more grammatically correct.

Am I right or am I missing something here?

Comment: Starting with *ça fait plus d'un an* is fine but *depuis je suis allé* after is not. Maybe was it *ça fait plus d'un an que j'y suis allé*.

Answer (score 3):

> (TLFi) c) **Plus de**, adj. déterminatif indéf. numéral ou quantitatif. [Suivi d'un nombre, d'une quantité, d'une expr. numérale, **pour marquer le dépassement d'un nombre, d'une quantité**] En quantité supérieure à. Anton. moins* de. Plus de la moitié; il est plus de minuit (synon. minuit passé*); enfant de plus de dix ans (synon. au-dessus de); il y a, voilà plus d'un an que. Les centres nerveux contiennent plus de douze milliards de cellules.

« Plus de » is followed by a description of a given quantity  and that quantity that has been mentionned is declared by means of « plus de » as superior to the given quantity. In English, **more than** is used.

- Il y a plus d'un sachet de pain sur la table.
  *There is more than one bag of bread on the table.*
  This means that on the table is found a bag of bread and may be half a bag on top of that, or several bags. If you use « plus que », you do not say that.
- Il faut plus d'un an d'étude pour ça, il en faut trois.
  *you need more than a year's study for that, 3 are needed.*

La définition  de « plus que » se trouve aussi dans le TLFi à l'entrée « plus ».

> **Plus que** Empl. de nom. **Une chose plus importante, une quantité ou une qualité supérieure**. Synon. davantage.
>   a) Plus que + compl. du compar. Vouloir être plus que qqn; en savoir plus que les autres, qu'on n'en peut retenir, qu'on n'en veut laisser paraître. Elle avait peut-être plus à dire à son petit livre que son petit livre n'avait à lui dire (A. FRANCE, P. Nozière, 1899, p.144). Tous les jours sont des dimanches et plus que des dimanches (PÉGUY, Myst. charité, 1910, p.13).

- Il y a plus qu'un sachet de pain sur la table.
  *There are other things than one  (a) bag of bread on the table.*
  *There are more things than one  (a) bag of bread on the table.*
  This means that on the table is found a bag of bread and besides that, other things which are not necessarily bread. If you use « plus de », you do not say that.
  The English of the translations is not ambiguous and corresponds exactly; however, if you say "There is more than a bag of bread on the table." it is not clear what you're talking about.
- He's got more than a house ; he's got land in the country and horses.
- Il faut plus qu'un an d'étude pour ça, il faut d'abord un brevet spécial, puis un an d'étude.
- You need more than a year's study for that, first you need a special diploma and then a year's study.

CONCLUSION

It must be "Ça fait **plus d'un an** que j'y suis allé." or "…que je suis allé là.*

Answer (score 1):

You are "technically" right if you stick to the literal translation but the fact is *de* replaces *que* in this sentence in French.

> *Ça fait **plus d'un an** que j'y suis allé.* (or *que je suis parti*)?.

The reason why is likely to avoid repeating "que". When it is not the case, *plus que* is also possible.

> *Ça fait un an que tu es parti.*
>
> *Non, ça fait **plus qu'un** an.*
>
> *Non, ça fait **plus d'un** an.*

Note that the ***s*** of *plu**s*** is generally mute in *plus d'un* (/plydœ̃/) while it is pronounced in *plu**s** qu'un* (/plyskœ̃/). Pronouncing the latter /plykœ̃/ would mean "only one (year left)".

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous responses, usage of "plus que" tends to correspond to situations where there is a decreasing quantity of something, and you're counting what remains: "Il n'y a plus que trois sachets de riz". This case also uses this strange negative form, which I can't explain properly. This is probably linked to the ambiguity of "plus" meaning either "more" or "none".

One thing to note is that as a native speaker I would rarely say "Il y a plus que 4 voitures" except in a situation where I have to spell things out unambiguously, such as explaining a proof in formal logic. In more casual speech I would prefer "plus de" which sounds less mechanical.